# Getting DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY when adding the drawer layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, illegalargumentexception, drawerlayout

I am trying to add drawerlayout in my fragment home. I am getting   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY. this error when I tried to attach drawer layout to my fragment.

I have root layout as constraint layout. Firstly I tried with root layout as drawerlayout still I wast getting this exception so I tried adding constraint layout to it but did not work.

It works when I give the hard coded value to height and width as 500dp.
But hard coded value cant be given as it will not be good practice for all devices size it will differ.

Below is my code

drawer layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout

    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/fragment_home"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/nav_header"
                layout="@layout/nav_header" />

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fadeScrollbars="true"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/menuItems"
                    layout="@layout/layout_navigation_menu" />
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Home fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_accept"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_55"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/green_500"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/app_bar">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:text="@string/accepting_orders"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_15"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:track="@drawable/switch_track_selector"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout_tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relative_accept">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_20"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:background="@drawable/grey_drawable"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                android:onClick="@{(v)->click.onClick(v)}"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout_tab" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Home fragment

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment() , View.OnClickListener{


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_layout_navigation_view, container, false)


    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        init()
        controlInit()
    }

    override fun init() {
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            (activity as MainActivity),
            drawer,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle)

        tabs.setupWithViewPager(view_pager)
        bindViewPagerAdapter(view_pager, (activity as MainActivity))
        bindViewPagerTabs(tabs, view_pager)
        tabSettings()
    }
    private fun tabSettings() {

        tabs.bringToFront()

        view_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
            override fun onPageScrolled(
                    position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetP: Int
            ) {
            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {}
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(i: Int) {}
        })
    }

    private fun bindViewPagerAdapter(view: ViewPager?, mainActivity: MainActivity) {
        val adapter = OrdersAdapter(view?.context!!, childFragmentManager)
        view.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun bindViewPagerTabs(view: TabLayout, pagerView: ViewPager?) {
        view.setupWithViewPager(pagerView, true)
    }

    private fun controlInit() {

        imageView_drawer.setOnClickListener(this)

    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    override fun onClick(p0: View) {
        when (p0.id) {
            R.id.imageView_drawer -> {
                drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() =
                HomeFragment().apply {}
    }
}
```

Please help with this.Thank you....

Answer (score 0):

Your layout actually worked just fine when I tested it so I am not sure if the issue lies with the layout. However your layout files are overly complex, you don't really need any of the nested layouts that you have and can achieve the same results without. `ConstraintLayout` was developed with the purpose of simplifying layout hierarchies so you should be able to just use that to organise your child views.

Also the `NavigationView` component is meant to be used to display a menu from a menu resource, not just to be used as a wrapper for your own. Either choose to display your own menu completely or use their implementation as intended. There is some nice documentation for this on the [Material Design website] [here](https://www.material.io/components/navigation-drawer/android#using-navigation-drawers).

So may I suggest you try to cut down on nesting your layouts and then see whether this incidentally fixes your problem.

The hierarchy that you might want would probably look something like this:

**drawer_layout.xml**

```
<DrawerLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/home" />
    <NavigationView />
</DrawerLayout>
```

**home.xml**

```
<ScrollView>
    <ConstraintLayout>
        <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"/>
        <TextView />
        <Switch />
        <TabLayout />
        <ViewPager />
    </ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```